# Saving a collection of records in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

Currently I have a part that has 3 fields (Name, Value1, Value2).  I have everything working where I can do a Create/Edit/Delete on the part.

What I want to do now is have a grid with 3 columns (Name, Value1, Value2) and can have multiple rows (up to the user how many there will be). The save won't happen until the user done (save all rows in a single post back).

I haven't figured what is needed so a collection of items will get saved on post back.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you could have is to have, in the part, a collection of the records corresponding to (Name, Value1, Value2) by having your dbms create and manage a 1-to-n relationship.

For example, you would have

```
public class ThisIsYourPart : ContentPart<ThisIsYourPartRecord> {
    // You can access the list of your records as
    // yourPart.Record.YourRecords

}

public class ThisIsYourPartRecord : ContentPartRecord {
    public ThisIsYourPartRecord () {
        YourRecords= new List<YourRecordWithValues>();
    }

    public virtual IList<YourRecordWithValues> YourRecords{ get; set; }
}

public class YourRecordWithValues {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Value1 { get; set; } // use your actual type
    public virtual ThisIsYourPartRecord  ThisIsYourPartRecord { get; set; }
}

public class YourMigration : DataMigrationImpl {
    public int Create() {

        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("YourRecordWithValues ", table => table
            .Column<int>("Id", col => col.Identity().PrimaryKey())
            .Column<string>("Name", col => col.NotNull().Unlimited())
            .Column<string>("Value1", col => col.NotNull().Unlimited())
            .Column<int>("ThisIsYourPartRecord_Id"));

        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("ThisIsYourPartRecord", table => table
            .ContentPartRecord());
    }
}
```

Code like that should do it.

We used this kind of relations a lot in https://github.com/bleroy/Nwazet.Commerce

*edit:
of course, have all the code in the proper files and folders.